# How to rewrite if statement to stop once .Count method has reached a number instead of continuously creating

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, xna-4.0

I am creating a brick breaker clone and need to stop creating blocks after 52 of them are created. The current situation i'm in once one is destroyed it creates more and actually goes into the 60's.

my Block code in the Update() section of Game 1:

```
if (blocks.Count < 52)
        {             

           for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
         {
               blockXpos += (61);
               blocks.Add(new Blocks(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks\\DurasteelBlock"), blockXpos, blockYpos));


               if (j == 11)
               {

                   for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                   {

                       blockXpos = 3;
                       blocks.Add(new Blocks(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks\\DurasteelBlock"), blockXpos, blockYpos));

                       blockYpos += (51);
                       if (i == 1)
                       {
                           j = 0;
                       }         
                   }
               }
           }
        }
```

The next bit of code is located directly below the above and is supposed to remove 1 from the .Count:

```
for (int j = 0; j < blocks.Count; j++)
            {
                if (blocks[j].alive == false)
                {
                    blocks.RemoveAt(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < blocks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (blocks[i].alive == false)
                {
                    blocks.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

My question is how do I change the very first line into basically saying *'stop after 52'* instead of *'continuously create if count is less than 52'*.

Comment: use a integer and count it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

After each blocks.Add you'd have to check blocks.Count and break out of the loop if it's >=52.

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove the if before the for loop

for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
{
    if (blocks.Count >= 52)
    {
        break; //exit the for loop
    }

    blockXpos += (61);
    blocks.Add(new Blocks(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks\\DurasteelBlock"), blockXpos, blockYpos));

    if (j == 11)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            blockXpos = 3;
            blocks.Add(new Blocks(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks\\DurasteelBlock"), blockXpos, blockYpos));
            blockYpos += (51);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                j = 0;
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

See [`break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) (MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put it into the LoadContent Section Instead Problem is solved now.